# Magnific popup not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

Magnific popup is working, but not the way I want it to.

Here is [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/N2bwn9DdrsWSzWwnVDcH?p=preview).

Why is it not working? Here is the jQuery code:

```
$('.view').click(function() {
    $('.image-popup').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        closeOnContentClick: true,
        mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
        image: {
            verticalFit: true
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you change your html to :

```
<div class="pic">
    <a  class="image-popup-fit-width" href="http://farm4.staticflickr.cm/3721/9207329484_ba28755ec4_o.jpg" title="This image fits only horizontally.">
    <img src="pictureLink" width="75" height="75">
  </a>
  <p><a href="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3721/9207329484_ba28755ec4_o.jpg" class="image-popup-fit-width">Click to view</a></p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The anchor tag needs to have image-popup-fit-width class rather image-popup.

```
<a  class="image-popup-fit-width" href="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3721/9207329484_ba28755ec4_o.jpg" title="This image fits only horizontally.">
        <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3721/9207329484_ba28755ec4_o.jpg" width="75" height="75">
</a>
```

Comment: any class name works even if I use image-popup-fit. but that's not my point. I want when someone click to view text  it will trigger the  popup.